# AVAudioSession's PlayAndRecord category and AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement are incompatible with defaultToSpeaker option?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

Attempting to put `AVAudioSession` into the `.playAndRecord` category with the `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement` mode causes the `.defaultToSpeaker` option to be ignored, resulting in output being played quietly out the earpiece (also known as the receiver).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there doesn't seem to be much written about this the documentation makes this "end result of audio output being sent to the receiver rather than speaker" seem like possible intended behavior and not a bug.

> **let AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement: String**
>
> This mode is intended for apps that need to minimize the amount of
>   system-supplied signal processing to input and output signals. If
>   recording on devices with more than one built-in microphone, the
>   primary microphone is used.

Comment: I created a bug report awhile back for a similar (possibly the same) issue, and Apple later closed it stating it was by design. https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=16402045

Comment: Thanks @Arda, since radars aren't public would you mind cross posting to openradar.me and sharing that link?